# Screen record and mouse tracking

Tags: windows, video, ubuntu, screen-recording, mouse

Is there any software that can record a screen as well as track mouse actions (xy-location, time, click) available. I could only find several programs that can change the mouse cursor to indicate whether left, right, neither button is clicked while the video is recorded; but I am looking for the one that can output log file reporting how the mouse is moving at each video frame or video recorded time.

Thanks in advance.

Edit1.1: I would like to use this software in my research: How users perform basic computer tasks such as move files and search for information from the internet. 
Edit1.2: Using 2 packages concurrently is fine as long as the time and and location of the two package are perfectly synchronized.

Comment: Which OS?  Free or paid?

Comment: Either Windows or Linux is fine. Free or paid is also fine; but free is more preferable. Because I really need the software that can do this specific task.

Comment: Welcome to softwarerecs.SE! Thank you for your question. Please [edit] your question to tell us two pieces of information: 1. Why do you want software which can do these things? 2. And would you be okay with having one software package which does screen recording plus a separate package which does mouse tracking?

Comment: @unforgettableid edited

Comment: Thanks for your edits. +1. So you're a usability researcher? Corporate, or academic? Do you have a homepage I could look at?

Comment: I am a computer science PhD student. I have not done any experiment yet. This is the very first step of the work which is looking for tools.
Thanks for your suggestion and +1.

Comment: @Yanagiba I don't know if you got the solution. I'm looking for the same and don't want to post a duplicate. I am about to try Open Vision Control, just in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, I'd use gtkRecordMyDesktop for the recordings.  AFAIK it doesn't support logging of mouse location, etc. though.

However, the [linux program `cnee`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cnee) does log X11 events and data.  It can even replay them back, distribute them to other machines, etc.

Quoth the man page -

> The program cnee can record and replay an X session. cnee also has the
>   ability to distribute events to multiple displays. cnee gets copies of
>   X protocol data from the X server. These are either printed to file (
>   record mode) or replayed and synchronised ( replay mode). During
>   record and replay cnee can distribute the record/replayed events to
>   multiple displays.

Checking the man page it does indeed log mouse X/Y coords and clicks - how often, etc and how granular it gets I don't know.  I also don't know how close you could time the 2 programs together - of course, `cnee` could do it all by itself for your purposes...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to record and playback user interactions with a website or a web application, then there are several viable solutions on the market that can help you to achieve just that.

While they won't necessarily give you a "raw export" of the underlying data, they (typically) provide different views and visualizations of that data, which might help you achieve your goals.

For example, some solutions provide different kinds of heat maps that can show you all the places people click or move their mouse pointer.

Other solutions provide visualizations that help you see how much time people spend on different parts of a webpage, as well as the points where they "drop off".

Depending on what you're looking to use that data for, these types of visualizations and analytics might be able to make up for the lack of the "raw data" you're looking for.

If that's the case, then here are some apps that you might want to consider checking out:

- [Tamboo - gettamboo.com](https://gettamboo.com)
- [Full Story - fullstory.com](https://fullstory.com)
- Lucky Orange - luckyorange.com
- HotJar - hotjar.com
- Inspectlet - inspectlet.com

I'm actually the founder of Tamboo, so if you have any specific questions about how this technology works or how you could use it to help you with your research, I might be able to help point you in the right direction (just ask!).